# Why div table cannot display border-right?

Tags: html, css

recently I want to build a table by `div`. I have set most of the setting.
However, when I input `border-right`. It does not show the border. Here is my code:

```css
.Forum{
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: table;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 95%;
    background:#6f7c85;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Forum .tableRow{
    display: table-row;     
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell1{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40%;
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell2{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
}
.Forum .tableRow .tableCell3{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: #e5eaef;
    border-right: 10px;
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell4{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: #e5eaef;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class = "Forum">
    <div class = "tableRow">
        <div class = "tableCell1" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Thread
        </div>
        <div class = "tableCell2" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Posted By
        </div>
        <div class = "tableCell2" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Last Post
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "tableRow">
        <div class = "tableCell3">Cotent 1</div>
        <div class = "tableCell4">Chris</div>
        <div class = "tableCell4">Today</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to apply  `border-collapse: collapse` to `.Forum`. However, it didn't work and it block the outer div also.
How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any application of `border-right` in your code.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do actually, sharing an image might be helpful

Comment: Like said, there isnt any border in your code. Then its very questionable why you use div's for table layout instead of suign a table or in the first place or a css-grid.

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake and I add the `border-right` in tableCell3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because You defined `border` property very early  `border: 10px;` this will create a border with 10px width but no style and no color, so You should create a rule to override this. That can be done by give rule more specifically or by using `!important` attribute. here I demonstrate the solution using `!important` attribute.

```css
.Forum{
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: table;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 95%;
    background:#6f7c85;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Forum .tableRow{
    display: table-row;
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell1{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40%;
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell2{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
}
.Forum .tableRow .tableCell3{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: #e5eaef;
    border: 10px;
}

.Forum .tableRow .tableCell4{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: #e5eaef;
    text-align: center; 
}

.table-cell{
  border-right:1px solid #000 ! important;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Forum">
    <div class = "tableRow">
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell1" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Thread
        </div>
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell2" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Posted By
        </div>
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell2" style = "text-align:center; color:white;">
        Last Post
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "tableRow">
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell3">Cotent 1</div>
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell4">Chris</div>
        <div class = "table-cell tableCell4">Today</div>
    </div>
</div>
```